# Screen Lag/Running Slow

Tags: 12.10, mouse, gui, input-devices

I am having trouble with Ubuntu 12.10. Everything is working fine, although there is a slight problem. It seems to lag every once in a while, as in I will move the mouse, then about two seconds later the cursor will actually move on the screen. Is there any way to fix this? This is my first day using Ubuntu and I put it on a computer I built myself. I don't have much experience so a detailed answer would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same symptom.
did you install any display drivers?
my solution is to remove the compiz or disable composite,but without that you can not enable desktop effects.

solution 1:

```
 sudo apt-get remove composite
```

solution 2:

=====remember to backup the original files!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!=====

```
sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

then add:

```
Section "Extensions"         
    Option  "Composite" "Disable"

EndSection
```

my laptop is using nVidia G102M,and with the method mentioned above i solved the problem.
my classmate told me that the problem may be caused by nVidia drivers
(i'm not using open-source drivers)

I hope this can help you

(my english is poor)

Comment: Hello. Your english is not poor at all! It is actually quite good. If I remove just the compiz will I still be able to enable desktop effects?

Comment: If you remove the compiz,the desktop effects will not work,but if you disable composite only(with the solution 2),other desktop effects may still work.
REMEMBER TO BACKUP THE ORIGINAL FILES!!!!